# Domain joined server is not identified as domain joined on the network profile

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2

IS there a way to force set this setting? The server is a Hyper-V server and the AD DS is hosted in a VM on this server. Is this going to be a problem?

I noticed this issue when my RDP connections stopped working to the main node which hosts all the VMs.

Comment: What is the domain joined computer in question using for DNS?

Comment: It uses the DNS for the AD DS/DNS server first as slot one. However, that server is in a Hyper-V container and boots up after the HOST node boots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution:

**Using Local Security Policy**

1. Open "Local Security Policy".
2. Click on "Network List Manager Policies" in the left pane. (This
   selection is buried in older versions of Windows.)
3. Double-click on "Unidentified Networks" in the right pane.
4. Set "Location type" to "private".

**Using Network Connection Properties**

5. Go to Network Connections (from the Network and Sharing Center,
   click on "Change adapter settings".)
6. Go to the properties of one network connection marked as
   "Unidentified" but on the private LAN.
7. Go to the properties for IPv4.
8. Click the "Advanced..." button.
9. Select the DNS tab.
10. Enter your domain name into the text box for "DNS suffix for this
    connection:".
11. Disable and then enable the connection to get NLA to re-identify the
    location.

Comment: I ran into a computer today that showed everything as Guest network whether on WiFi or wired.  I checked the local security policy, and the Network List Manager Policies were all missing.

Answer (score 1):

While you should probably solve the underlying problem, there are ways to  manually control NLA. There is a fairly comprehensive [TechNet blog post(archive.org)](https://web.archive.org/web/20150317051942/http://blogs.technet.com/b/networking/archive/2010/09/08/network-location-awareness-nla-and-how-it-relates-to-windows-firewall-profiles.aspx) with details on how to do this.

Comment: Have you defined all your subnets in AD Sites & Services? -- Unless this is done automatically when you install AD DS/DNS, then no. At least not that I remember. I never knew about this. I'll give this a try.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. AD Sites and Services isn't related to NLA. From Microsoft: **The domain network location type is detected when the local computer is a member of an Active Directory domain, and the local computer can authenticate to a domain controller for that domain through one of its network connections.** - If you have links to information that relates NLA to ADS&S, please post it.

Comment: Thanks joeqwerty, I thought I had seen documentation about this but can't find it. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately the provided link no longer works.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem with both Windows Server 2008 R2 and 2012 R2. After trying all sorts of things, the fix was simple in the end in my case.
I had originally set Windows Firewall to block all Public network traffic, thinking I was exercising due diligence security-wise, considering that the servers wouldn't have a reason to communicate over a public network. The problem is that, when a server starts by default, it will start at Public network mode. It then communicates with the DC to determine if it will switch to Domain network mode. However, if all Public traffic is blocked, then it has no way of establishing contact with the DC and hence will stick to Public network mode. The fix was simple - enable outbound traffic in Public network mode.
Another relevant thing I noticed is that when Public network was being fully blocked, attempting to ping out from the server resulted in "General failure" responses. This threw me off track because such a result in past experience had indicated a fault more with the NIC driver/hardware (rather than a firewall block).